# Is there a way to add hotkeys to tabs in Visual Basic .NET that is as simple as adding one to a button?

Tags: vb.net, hotkeys

I would like functionality to use hotkeys between some of my tabs. However, adding an "&" in front of a letter does not work with tabs like it does buttons.

Comment: Assuming this is WinForms and that you're talking about `TabControl`, unfortunately, it doesn't support mnemonic keys. You'd have to either handle the `KeyDown` event and write the logic yourself or create/use a custom tab control. Here are two examples: [1](https://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/20269-tabControl-with-Hotkeys-Disabling-individual.aspx), [2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12011/MnemonicTabControl-a-tabcontrol-with-accelerator-k).

Comment: If you have a MenuStrip, you *could* add tab navigation to that… not sure whether that’s better or worse.

Comment: Another option would be to [override ProcessCmdKey()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63090213/2330053), and select your desired tab.

Comment: do you mean tabs, as field on a window, or tabs as in a windows.forms.tab control, for the former try focus, for the later try Me.TabControl.TabIndex = x